# javascript converts regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Somehow browser converts regex pattern `[a-z0-9+&@#%=~_|!,.:;\?\/\-]` to this `[a-z0-9+â€Œâ€‹&@#%=~_|\/\-]` in user side. JS file is coded with utf8 without BOM and every other symbols does not change just these. How it could be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

`â€Œ` is a ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
`â€‹` is a ZERO WIDTH SPACE

Maybe these came from copying the regex from elsewhere, but it's fairly obvious that they aren't intended parts of the regex.

Your problem can be solved by re-typing your regex (do NOT copy-paste it)

Comment: A quick way to check if it's copy/pasting invisible characters is to paste [here](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/string-functions.php) and verifying. The character count and the Show Hidden Characters tools might help.